# Pass values from ASP.NET to Silverlight application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have created an ASP.NET project in Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express on the .web part and included a Silverlight project. I have created something like a music blog, and I want to pass the "path" value to Silverlight. The user uploads the file and the track will be played in the Silverlight app.

I have created for example in the database a table called Posts and another table deriving from Posts called Track, where the path of the file is stored. I have also included in my Index.aspx file:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:50%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="770" height="530">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/MusicBlog.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Holen Sie sich Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
```

When creating a Post I call:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(Posts model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Music"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    Track track = new Track();
                    track.Path = path;
                    model.Track.Add(track);
                    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
                    Posts post = new Posts();
                    /*post.Body = model.Body;
                    post.Created = model.Created;
                    post.Modified = model.Modified;
                    post.Title = model.Title;*/
                    model.Created.ToLocalTime();
                    postRepository.Create(model);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The given Path is invalid");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The given Path is invalid");
            }

        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

How can I pass now the path to the player in Silverlight, so I can play the track, in the Silverlight app which is embedded in the ASP.NET page?

Comment: You are aware Microsoft dumped Silverlight for the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Create an overload for Index

```
public ActionResult Index(string trkPath) { }
```

and add Route Values while redirecting

```
return(RedirectToAction("Index", new { trkPath = track.Path }));
```

and access the params in silverlight

```
NavigationContext.QueryString["trkPath"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Silverlight to access the track on the local file system, the user will have to initiate the selection, you can't access the file system "for them."  You could in Silverlight out-of-browser applications running with elevated trust (and you can actually do it in [Silverlight 5 in browser](http://silverlightedweb.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-get-unrestricted-access-in.html), but that's an edge case).

Why not have the Silverlight app prompt for the track and upload it as well?

Comment: Because then it's getting to complicated. I have the Create.aspx where the "Title", "Body", "File" is uploaded. On the Details.aspx The silverlight app is attached and is supposed to get the path and play the each track. Those values are saved in the database. Is it maybe possible to retrieve the data from there? So that the silverlight gets the id of the post and plays the track it's assigned to?